# it is possible to make a copy of an iPhone?

Tags: forensics, iphone, unix

Is it possible to make a copy (an image like `iso` or `img`) of an iPhone  supposing that we can only connect it to a computer?

Can I use the `dd` command to do this? Are any alternative ways to a clone an iPhone ?

Comment: I believe it would have to be jail broken in order to make a full image of the device.  Otherwise I doubt you'd have permissions to read the entire volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple itunes backup actually backs everything up, down to the arrangement of apps on the home screens. to use the backup, you'd need another iphone to restore the backup to, that is capable of running the same version of iOS.
i would expect you'd need to know the passcode of the phone, to do the backup in the first place. it might also ask for the icloud password, on the cloned iphone. i can't remember.